# Numbers sequencing and decoding... (#1)

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

Part 1:

Q1,E2,T3,U4,O5,A6,D7,___

Find ___.

> Clue: draobyek

Part 2:

ode coded math is slogan done bans were math eroded question: eco desperate minus 14362

i22096

up ____ down. eulc?

> Clue: Word sin words!!! Side.

Solve this question!!! There is a message.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to part 1 is

> G8

as this is

> the order on a standard QWERTY keyboard, as given in the clue.

I'm not motivated enough to solve part 2 ...

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 already answered by WhatsUp.  Incomplete thoughts on a solution to part 2:

> There are words hidden inside the long string of words:
>
> o**de code**d ma**th is** slog**an d**one b**ans wer**e ma**th e**roded question: eco desperate minus 14362
>
> Not sure if this is supposed to read "decode this and answer the question" since "question" is not hidden within other words. The rest might say "code minus 14362" although again I'm not sure why "minus" wouldn't be hidden within other words like everything else.  Alternately it could say "decode this and answer the one ???"